# Finding a total score on variable with SPSS

Tags: spss

I have imputed my questions to the numeric expression box, I have been told to put brackets around the (+) for every question and then use / to divide by the total questions however I get this error every time:
A minimum number of non-missing arguments following a function name contains a non-numeric character.
I just need to find the total score please can someone help :)